# pnmtops subprocess hang when called from a scanadf script

Tags: scanner, sane

I have been happily using `scanadf` with the `-S script --script-wait`
parameters for a couple of years.

My script, called `scan_perpage`, converts the image data to pdf, via a call to `pnmtops`, piped
through `ps2pdf`.

However recently (I suspect since I updated from Fedora 17 to 19), the
called script hangs, and therefore `scanadf` hangs. The script is hung
at the `pnmtops` command. The `pnmtops` command itself is waiting for its
forked "child" `pnmtops` output filter to complete, and it never does.

Running the `scan_perpage` script directly on the raw scanner page output works fine. Running the `pnmtops` command directly also works fine. It is only when run from `scanadf` via `-S` that the script hangs at `pnmtops`.

Versions:

```
# rpm -q --info sane-backends
Name        : sane-backends
Version     : 1.0.23
Release     : 13.fc19

# rpm -q --info sane-frontends
Name        : sane-frontends
Version     : 1.0.14
Release     : 16.fc19

# rpm -q --info netpbm
Name        : netpbm
Version     : 10.61.02
Release     : 5.fc19
```

Here is the output of my `scan` script, which calls `scanadf -vv`:

```
$ scan -o output.pdf
Scanning...
scanadf: value for --resolution is: 300
scanadf: scanning image of size 2544x3300 pixels at 1 bits/pixel
scanadf: acquiring gray frame
Started script `/usr/local/bin/scan_perpage' as pid=10902
Scanned document scan-0001
pnmtops: Input maxval is 1.  Postscript raster will have 1 bits per
sample, so maxval = 1
pnmtops: Image will be 610.56 points wide by 792.00 points high, left
edge 0.72 points from left edge of page, bottom edge 0.00 points from
bottom of page; NOT turned to landscape orientation
pnmtops: output filter spawned: pid 10904
pnmtops: Waiting for PID 10904 to exit
Scanned 1 pages
<the script hangs here>
```

Here is the process tree at the point of the hang:

```
10897 32072 /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/scan -o output.pdf
10898 10897 scanadf -vvv -d fujitsu -S /usr/local/bin/scan_perpage
--script-wait --resolution 300 --mode Lineart -o scan-%04d
10902 10898 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/scan_perpage scan-0001
10903 10902 pnmtops -verbose -imagewidth 8.5 -imageheight 11 scan-0001
10904 10903 pnmtops -verbose -imagewidth 8.5 -imageheight 11 scan-0001
```

Process 10904 (the forked `pnmtops` "output filter") never finishes. An
strace indicates it is waiting on a "read".

I can't figure out why `pnmtops` hangs when called via `scanadf`, but when
called directly on the same file it works perfectly fine.

In addition, if the `pnmtops` subprocess is killed manually, everything continues without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Bryan Henderson, maintainer of netpbm:

> I found and fixed a bug that causes this symptom.  [...] The fix is in Netpbm 10.64.02.
>
> The difference in environment that causes Pnmtops sometimes to hang
>   and sometimes not is the number of open files.  If there are more than
>   10 open files when Pnmtops gets invoked, the hang happens.
>
> In case you care what the pathology is: The child exits when the pipe
>   feeding it signals EOF.  That happens when every copy of the file
>   descriptor for the sending end of the pipe closes.  The only copy
>   that's supposed to exist is the one the parent process is writing data
>   to.  But the child necessarily inherits copies of the file descriptors
>   for both ends of the pipe.  If the child doesn't close its copy of the
>   *sending* end of the pipe, the child will never see EOF on the receiving end, so will wait forever.
>
> That means the child must close its copy of the sending end of the
>   pipe that is feeding it.  To do this, and fix some other similar
>   problems, the child attempts at startup to close every file descriptor
>   besides the two it actually uses.  But POSIX doesn't provide a way to
>   know the list of open file descriptors, so the child just blindly
>   closes 0-9 (excluding the two it needs), knowing that Pnmtops would
>   not use more files than that.  The mistake was that the program didn't
>   account for file descriptors the process was born with.  The fix is
>   for Pnmtops to close file descriptors 0-9 when it starts up, so that
>   any pipes it creates will have file descriptor numbers in the range
>   0-9 and thus get closed by the blind 0-9 close.

Comment: The Fedora Bugzilla bug associated with this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1029512